# How to get all list of objects in buckets including tags in single request from S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using listObjectsV2 to list all the objects from AWS s3 bucket.But
that list does not contain tags and metadata.I have gone through the documentation and came to know that metadata details we can get separately
by fetching one by one object.But is there any way can we get tags and metadata of files from s3 bucket in one method?

Note: I am using AWS-SDK(Node.js) version 2.x

Answer (score 1):

The underlying S3 service API has no method for fetching listings along with object metadata and/or tags, so none of the SDKs implement such functionality, either.

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) provides comma-separated values (CSV) or Apache optimized row columnar (ORC) output files that list your objects and their corresponding metadata on a daily or weekly basis for an S3 bucket or a shared prefix (that is, objects that have names that begin with a common string).

It can be configured to run on a daily basis.

Comment: Thanks for the info.But I want to get that data from API call.Just thinking is there
any workaround to do so.And in the same way  can't  we search the objects based on metatag or tags also?